# Count Not Null Columns using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

i have a table "tbl_userpersonal",

what i want to achieve is check which columns are filled and which are not so i can calculate or display the profile completion percentage.
\

So far i've tried a lot of different techniques and codes and my code is counting all columns but i want it to count empty value columns as 0.
please help me with a solutions.

So far if there is even a single entry for a user in any column it's giving me 100% otherwise 0% there is no inbetween

Currently if there is value inside "father_name" & "mother_name" & "DOB" column for a user with user_authtoken = "app_7837hfjd57hdj" the expected output should be
3
50% i.e (3/6)*100

what is happening right now is

if there is value inside either of these columns for a user with user_authtoken = "app_7837hfjd57hdj" the output is showing as

6
100%  i.e (6/6)*100

or if there is no entry for user with user_authtoken = "app_7837hfjd57hdj" the output is giving 
0
0%

[image]

here is the php code

```
    $personal = mysqli_query($con,"

     SELECT   father_name,
     mother_name,
     DOB,
     adhar_no,
     address,
     religion,
     CASE WHEN father_name IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
     CASE WHEN mother_name IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
     CASE WHEN DOB IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
     CASE WHEN adhar_no IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
     CASE WHEN address IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
     CASE WHEN religion IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS personal
     FROM  user WHERE `user_authtoken` = '$user_ath'

     ") or die(mysqli_error($con));

      $data=mysqli_fetch_assoc($personal);
      $pro_count =  $data['personal'];
      echo $pro_count ; 
      echo '<br>';
      $percentage = ($pro_count /6)*100;
      echo $percentage;
```

Comment: Please provide a relevant and minimal sample data showcasing your requirements, and expected output. Refer this link on how to frame a good SQL question: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya I've updated my question can you look into it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i think you have empty value in table not null try this

*this will check for null as well as empty*

```
$personal = mysqli_query($con,"

     SELECT   father_name,
     mother_name,
     DOB,
     adhar_no,
     address,
     religion,
     CASE WHEN father_name IS NOT NULL AND father_name<>'' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
     CASE WHEN mother_name IS NOT NULL AND mother_name<>'' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
     CASE WHEN DOB IS NOT NULL AND DOB<>'' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
     CASE WHEN adhar_no IS NOT NULL AND adhar_no<>'' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
     CASE WHEN address IS NOT NULL AND address<>'' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
     CASE WHEN religion IS NOT NULL AND religion<>'' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS personal
     FROM  user WHERE `user_authtoken` = '$user_ath'

     ") or die(mysqli_error($con));
```